# Send single status update email using addresses listed in Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, unique, array-formulas

We have a Google Sheet that has a few columns (3 at the moment, and not sequential so say column B, D, and G) with email addresses. Some of these email addresses are duplicated through the sheet. Once a week we would like to send an email to all the addresses (one email per address) with a new link to the sheet for them to review.

What is the best way to pull all the email addresses, and then filter that to a unique list, and send a standard email (the email will be the same for all addresses).

Thanks in advance, been working on this for awhile, got the emailing portion down, just trying to determine the best way to get the list of addresses out of the existing sheet.

Comment: post the code you have so far. also its likely google apps script and not appengine. tag correctly.

Comment: No need for grammar nazi's....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering mainly your last sentence:

```
=ArrayFormula(sort(unique({B1:B;D1:D;G1:G})))
```

Comment: Think that may do what we want, then we can run our email script against that list. Will test it tomorrow and post an update. Thanks!